Data transmission between an Arduino and Stepper motor question
I have 2 stepper motor units attached to an Arduino with the typical red and black wires. I bought the unit used from a third party. Could there anyway for there to be a malware to be on the motor unit to transmit to the Arduino and then my PC while all connected.
Or is it not possible because the red and black wires just transmit 0 and 1s from the Arduino to the motor unit and not the other way around.

Can you clarify what the stepper motor units attached to an Arduino with the typical red and black wires is. E.g. do you have a part number or a link to a datasheet?

if it has only two wires,  then it is not a stepping motor

Stepper motors need to have at least 4 wires to be a stepping motor.  If it is just 2 wires that just make the motor spin when you apply a DC voltage to them, then you just have a standard DC motor.  As far as malware goes, if this is a DC motor there is no way that I know of to "store" code in them to be used as a malware payload.  To use the electricity / water analogy that we often do in electronics, it is like worrying about opening the faucet in your home and the Anarchists Cook Book squirts out.
